# Can we [fitler] this tag out?

Tags: discussion

I think we should burnate the [fitler](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitler) tag since it is just a typo and [filter](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) was made. It was used in [this question](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/q/40/4) but an edit fixed the typo with the tag.

Comment: Hi @ethan I made that edit and agree!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unused tags are automatically deleted after a while.  If you simply stop making the typo, the tag will vanish.